# How to make an activity background completely transparent (not translucent)?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android `activity`, I need to make the background of the activity transparent. For that, I found solutions online saying to do this in theme.

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

However this makes the `activity` background translucent i.e it isn't perfectly transparent, it is slightly grey. Is there a way to get a perfectly transparent background such that the screen below it is perfectly viisible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: In this case, please, share your complete style for transparent theme.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<style name="TransparentTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

Usage

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity"
        android:theme="@style/TransparentTheme.Base" />
```